# How is this evaluating as false?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

[image: screenshot of google chrome developer tools showing that both objects have value]

When I step through this code, the values pictured result in cssLoaded = 0;  From what I can see, the length is greater than 0 and cssStylesheet.sheet has properties so should be true, therefore cssLoaded should be set to 1, however it's not happening.  I must be missing something here..?

```
function _cssIsLoaded(cssStylesheet, stylePath) {
var cssLoaded = 0;
if (tryCount == 3){
    console.log('oops');
}
if (cssStylesheet.href == stylePath){
    try {
        if ( cssStylesheet.sheet && cssStylesheet.sheet.cssRules.length > 0 ){
            cssLoaded = 1;}
        else if ( cssStylesheet.styleSheet && cssStylesheet.styleSheet.cssText.length > 0 ){
            cssLoaded = 1;}
        else if ( cssStylesheet.innerHTML && cssStylesheet.innerHTML.length > 0 ){
            cssLoaded = 1;}
        }
        catch(ex){ }
}
    if(cssLoaded) {
        //alert('cssloadedcomplete');
        resetPops();
        $('#video-overlay').show();
        positionElements();
        saveBizzmail();
        console.log('try:' + tryCount)
    } else {
        tryCount+=1;
        console.log('try:' + tryCount);
        setTimeout(function() { this._cssIsLoaded(cssStylesheet); }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this condition: `if (cssStylesheet.href == stylePath){` pass?

Comment: what does `cssStylesheet.sheet` evaluate to?

Comment: @jasonbar wow.. yup. like a horse with blinders on! :p that did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possible ways your code gets cssLoaded == 0;

1. `if (cssStylesheet.href == stylePath)` evaluates to `false`.
2. All three `if/else` statements evaluate to `false`.
3. One of the `if/else` statements throws an exception and thus the other `if/else` statements aren't executed.

In troubleshooting your issue, you should verify that the first two are not the issue as those are probably just logic errors in the comparisons or the data coming into the function isn't what you expected it to be.

For the third issue, you can implement defensive coding to make sure that all three `if/else` statements are checked by changing your code to this (you don't even need the try/catch any more because it allows your code to bypass some of the tests):

```
function _cssIsLoaded(cssStylesheet, stylePath) {
    var cssLoaded = 0;
    if (tryCount == 3){
        console.log('oops');
    }
    if (cssStylesheet && cssStylesheet.href == stylePath) {
        if ( cssStylesheet.sheet && cssStylesheet.sheet.cssRules && cssStylesheet.sheet.cssRules.length > 0 ) {
            cssLoaded = 1;
        }
        else if ( cssStylesheet.styleSheet && cssStylesheet.styleSheet.cssText && cssStylesheet.styleSheet.cssText.length > 0 ) {
            cssLoaded = 1;
        }
        else if ( cssStylesheet.innerHTML && cssStylesheet.innerHTML.length > 0 ) {
            cssLoaded = 1;
        }
    }
    if(cssLoaded) {
        //alert('cssloadedcomplete');
        resetPops();
        $('#video-overlay').show();
        positionElements();
        saveBizzmail();
        console.log('try:' + tryCount)
    } else {
        tryCount+=1;
        console.log('try:' + tryCount);
        setTimeout(function() { this._cssIsLoaded(cssStylesheet); }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for the existence of the element, otherwise an error may occur (`cssStylesheet.sheet` is `undefined`). An expression will evaluate to false when:

- The variable doesn't exist (`undefined`, `null`, `void 0`)
- Equals `0` (zero)
- Equals `false`
- Equals an empty string (`""`, `''`)
- A Not-a-number value (`0/0`, `NaN`)

Note that an empty object `{}` evaluates to true, because it's an object.

Another example:

```
if(window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", function(){}, true);
else if(window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", function(){});
else window.onload = function();
```

If the if-conditions were not present, the code will throw an error at older versions of IE, which don't have such a method called `window.addEventListener`.

Comment: makes sense.. my main question, though, is why both or either would be 'false' in the above situation. That other question wasn't really related.. just stream of consciousness.. I edited it out.

Comment: If, *One*: "Does `cssStylesheet.sheet` exists?"
If, *Two*: "Is the length property of `cssStylesheet.sheet.cssRules` greater than 0"? If *One* and *Two* are true, the expression is evaluated. The first expression is used to prevent JavaScript errors, the second expressions is specific function logic.

Answer (score 1):

The former check ensures that you avoid an NPE like situation (by checking that `cssStylesheet.sheet` is not null).